# onClick function within another function

Tags: javascript, function, onclick

I'm fairly new to JS and hoping someone can help me with an issue I'm having while I'm trying to build a demo gallery. I have a JSON file called feed.js and I'm calling certain fields in that JSON file (i.e. the image URL) into a HTML table and that's working no problem. What I'm trying to do next is that when a user clicks on the image the, the cells beside the image populate with more fields called from the JSON file. This is what I have so far but myFunction is outside f is defined so I'm getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: f is not defined" when I click the image. Any ideas of how to get around this would be great! Sorry if this is a real novice question but as I said I'm a newbie!

```
<script>
$(function() {

    var feed = [];

    $.getJSON('feed.json', function(data) {
        $.each(data.phones, function(i, f) {
            var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td><div id=\"demo1\"><img onclick=\"myFunction()\" id=\"demo\" src=" + f.image + "></div></td></tr>";
            $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");

        });
    });

});

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "<tr>" + "<td><div id=\"demo1\"><img onclick=\"myFunction()\" id=\"demo\" src=" + f.image + "></div></td><td>"+ f.description + "</td><td>" + f.manufacturer + "</td></tr>;"
};
</script>
```

Comment: your question is unclear

Comment: You're using jQuery in your project, but then seem to be using a mix of jQuery and vanilla JavaScript for DOM selection and traversal.  This is just a matter of opinion, but I find it makes for cleaner solutions when you commit to one approach-- either committing to jQuery or going all-in on JavaScript.  Again, just a matter of opinion.

Answer (score 0):

on this line

```
 var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td><div id=\"demo1\"><img onclick=\"myFunction()\" id=\"demo\" src=" + f.image + "></div></td></tr>";
```

you are setting common id to each row into your table, change this.

secondly,

remove '\' from your structure, this is endLine character.

this might be what you are looking for..

```
 $.getJSON('feed.json', function(data) {
    $.each(data.phones, function(i, f) {
        var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td><div><img onclick='myFunction()' src=" + f.image + "></div></td></tr>";
        $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");

    });
});
```

Comment: shouldn't this be a comment more than an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using an `onclick`, you should set a [`jQuery event listener`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) on the target element from within the function scope that you're defining `myFunction`.  Since you're `img` has an `id`, you can target it in that manner.  Something like this:

```
<script>
$(function() {

    var feed = [];

    function myFunction() {
      document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = "<tr>" + "<td><div id=\"demo1\"><img id=\"demo\" src=" + f.image + "></div></td><td>"+ f.description + "</td><td>" + f.manufacturer + "</td></tr>";
    }

    $.getJSON('feed.json', function(data) {
        $.each(data.phones, function(i, f) {
            var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td><div id=\"demo1\"><img id=\"demo\" src=" + f.image + "></div></td></tr>";
            $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");

        });
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#demo', myFunction); // everytime the user clicks on an element with id #demo inside the document, myFunction will be called

});

</script>
```